# Android Layout topbar > scrollview > advert bar

Tags: android, xml, layout

Hi currently i am really struggling to get a nice layout for my android app.
Im planing on making a view with a header and a footer that surround a scrollview ive tried lots of situations but all the my bottom bar dissapears from my scrollview.

To make things more clear ive made a simple image of what i'dd like it to be:

[Mockup](http://imageshack.us/f/696/layoutezc.jpg/)

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">    

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/toplayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

          <TextView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
            android:text="TopBar"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
          android:id="@+id/bottomlayout"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

          <TextView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
            android:text="Bottom Bar"/>
    </RelativeLayout>   

    <ScrollView 
            android:id="@+id/scrolllayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/toplayout"
            android:layout_above="@id/bottomlayout">
         <RelativeLayout
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        <ImageView 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:background="@drawable/icon01"
              android:id="@+id/lin1"/>
       </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>   


</RelativeLayout>
```